# An Immigrant from Windows, please help with applications

Tags: software-recommendation

Please name the software similar to the ones I will mention from Windows:

- Internet Download Manager (IDM)
- K-Lite Codec Pack         (KLC)
- CCleaner
- TuneUp Utilities
- Winrar

Comment: Please note that Ubuntu users (such as the people on this site) don't know as much about Windows programs as you do. Hence, you may not get a good answer, because we don't understand, why something called "CCleaner" could possible be useful. More specifically, you are asking about utilities that appear fix problems of the Windows OS. It's likely that now or in the future, those utilities will not be needed if you get yourself a better OS (such as Ubuntu).

Comment: I'm voting this question down because I believe that 'TuneUp Utilities' is just a registry cleaner. (Although I find Ubuntu-Tweak handy)

Answer (score 8):

Various links below to good AskUbuntu questions & Answers:

- Internet Download Manager (IDM) --> [Lot of choice](https://askubuntu.com/q/32850/62483) e.g. GwGet
- K-Lite Codec Pack (KLC) --> Use `vlc` or just install all the restricted codecs, i.e.:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-codecs
  ```
- CCleaner --> [Lots of choice again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2243/ccleaner-equivalent) - e.g. BleachBit, UbuntuTweak
- TuneUp Utilities --> Again use BleachBit, UbuntuTweak
- Winrar --> [Lots of choice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41791/whats-the-easiest-way-to-unrar-a-file)... e.g. use the inbuilt Archiver (file-roller) or something like 7-Zip

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you top enable multiverse repository in software sources:

[image] and then install the package `ubuntu-restricted-extras` and `ubuntu-restricted-addon` which will install most of the restricted codecs, flashplugin, unrar, microsoft fonts etc. If you need more restricted codecs you may install [medibuntu](http://medibuntu.org/) repository as well. You may try `mplayer` `vlc`as well for multimedia. Other than that there are [lists](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/list-of-download-managers-available-in-ubuntu.html) of download manager although I personally prefer [DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) of Firefox. As for tuneups and cleaning utility I would like to add [ailurus](http://code.google.com/p/ailurus/) to the mix.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is not alternative to IDM in Ubuntu but you can use DownThemAll firefox extension [Here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/)
2. `sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly vlc`
3. `sudo apt-get install bleachbit`
4. There is no alternative for TuneUp Utilities in Ubuntu because you dont need it.
5. `sudo apt-get install unrar unzip`