# What's the easiest way to unrar a file on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, rar

I just realized I can't unrar .rar files on my Ubuntu machine!

Comment: yes but the details that i was looking for failed

Comment: Here: http://askubuntu.com/a/323716/158442, then use the default archiving program.

Answer (score 259, accepted):

1. First you need to install `unrar`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install unrar
   ```
2. If you want to unpack all files within the `.rar` files in the same directory:

   ```
   unrar e -r /home/work/software/myfile.rar
   ```
3. if you want to unpack the files in full path:

   ```
   unrar x -r /home/work/software/myfile.rar
   ```

Comment: It seems like in 16.04 at least, the standard file roller program will do rars too once you've got unrar installed.

Comment: This applies to Ubuntu 18.* too. The standard archive manager was able to open rar files once I installed unrar.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install unrar-free` worked when I got "Package 'unrar' has no installation candidate" on Ubuntu 16.04 when I did `sudo apt-get install unrar`.

Comment: Even in 14.04 after installing unrar normal file viewer will open .rar files

Comment: Only the craziest of us would do `e`, oh god, why is this flag ever exists???

Comment: unrar e? i think if we don't even know what would happen then it's better to just answer '/h'. what you think is ok, most don't

Comment: @ieXcept I am using it right now! I have a set of .rar files, and some have been packaged with the files in the root, and some have been packaged with all files in a subfolder. I want a normalised process, so I use `e` to extract them to a homogenous structure.  It's not what you normally need, but when you do need it it saves a lot of time.