# How to download files (rar, zip ...) via browser on Ubuntu-Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, downloads, browser

how can i download rar file via native browser in Ubuntu-Touch aquaris e4,5?

I get the messages:
"Sorry there arent currently any apps installed that can handle this type of content"

Comment: Why did this get a downvote?

Comment: [This Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41791/whats-the-easiest-way-to-unrar-a-file) describes how to add `unrar`/`rar` support to Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

I came to find an answer but then I have figured it out myself, from terminal type

wget http://link.zip

(replace link.zip with your link to download)

Comment: While this is a way to download files otherwise not handleable, I feel there could be a downloader app that can handle all file types and will just place them in ~/Downloads.